# Select data from current, last, previous month and echo on chart

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Hi I need to show total amount debited for 3 month(separately) and show them on a COLUMN CHART.

(I have included session_start and $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'])

And I think my $query2 and $query3 are wrong, I want to select sum ONLY from last month instead of combining the last month & current month.

So, `$query1` = SUM for current month, `$query2` = SUM for last_month, `$query3` = SUM for last 2 month.

```
$query1 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS current_debit FROM account WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date)";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$currentMonth_debit = $row ['current_debit'];

$query2 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS last_debit FROM account WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$lastMonth_debit = $row2 ['last_debit'];

$query3 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS prev_debit FROM account WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
$prevMonth_debit = $row3 ['prev_debit'];
```

After that, how do I show $currentMonth_debit, $lastMonth_debit, $prevMonth_debit on Google chart? Should I create an array like..

```
$pieData[] = array($row['$currentMonth_debit'], $row['lastMonth_debit'], $row['$prevMonth_debit']);
```

This is my google chart page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Money Out'],
      [<?php echo $pieData ?>],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Total Money Out',
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
```

When I run this code, the chart doesn't come out. Please help! :(

Comment: The good old Bobby Tables advice: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: As far as I can see there is no risc of SQL injection here. There is a `$user_id`, but this is most likely a local internal variable.

Comment: @davidkinrad, even if you're right (and I think its dangerous to assume you are in this case), using parameter binding is easy enough and is good coding practice.  If you get in the habit of always using it, your likelihood of having an "oops, I forgot" moment when it counts is severely diminished.

Comment: @davidkonrad huh? So I should just stick to using 3 queries? If so, how do I solve my problem?

Comment: It is possible to write this as a single query, but you have to decide exactly what you want to include in each category.

Comment: @asgallant - you are right, but the comment was obviously not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please do yourself and your users a favor and use parameter binding on your queries:

```
$query1 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS current_debit FROM account WHERE user_id=? AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $currentDebit);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

$query2 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS last_debit FROM account WHERE user_id=? AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $lastDebit);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

$query3 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS prev_debit FROM account WHERE user_id=? AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $prevDebit);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

In order to get the queries right, you have to decide exactly what you mean by "current month", "last month", and "last 2 months".

Putting the data in the correct format is easy:

```
$pieData = array(
    array('Month', 'Money Out'),
    array('Current Month', $currentMonth),
    array('Last Month', $lastMonth),
    array('Previous 2 months', $prevMonth)
);
```

and in your javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($pieData, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

Comment: The king of GV :-) +1 for demonstrating parameter binding in the answer. This was constructive.